# How to render after authentication with JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Application in Nodejs and Express.
Authentication with JWT.
I have implemented the authentication system with JWT and with Postman it works perfectly. The problem comes when after passing the request authentication middleware and go through the controller that manages the GET of the page I want to render, I receive the response and deal with res.text () that returns a string of text.
In the text string I get the full page I want, I render it with document.write (resBody), this updates the content with the new page but does not update neither the history nor the browser window, which is a little bit botched.
Is there any way to render the response in javascript?
Thank you

```
// index.hbs
...
...
...
<form id="enter"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="enter">
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar"> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const formEnter = document.querySelector('#enter')
    formEnter.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        token = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token')
        fetch('/api/brands',{
            method:'get',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'Authorization': token
            }
    .then(function(response) {
       return response.text()
    }).then(resBody => {
       document.write(resBody)  //<--- resBody tiene la página que quiero renderizar
    })
</script>


//brandCtrl.js

...
...


function getBrands(req,res){
    Brand.find({}, (err,brands) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error en la petición: ${err}`})
        if (!brands) return res.status(404).send({message: `No se existen Marcas en la BD`})

        res.locals.brands = brands
        res.render("brands/brands",res.locals.brands)
    })
}


...
...
```

Comment: IN your getBrands try res.json({brands: brands}) instead res.render()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by "render the response in javascript". You can either expect your node application to return a json response (using res.json(YOUR RESPONSE JSON)) or render a template (res.render('some template')) on authenticating successfully.

You are not using fetch API correctly. Your request expects a JSON response , but you are sending an html string as a response.

If you want to render the html page using javascript. you can use jquery:

```
$('body').load( url,[data],[callback] );
```

You can checkout the documentation here. http://api.jquery.com/load/#urldatacallback

Then you can change the browser history by using history.pushState . But all of this is already done by any frontend framework. So either use one or do this manually.

Comment: The second option. Render a page. That's why I use res.render ("brands / brands"). Authentication has been successful and I receive in index.js the page to render but I can not show it with anything else than document.write(<page received in text format>)
I still see the page (index.js) from which I called the page with authentication control.
If I try to login without authenticating before, it sends me to an error page 403. That is resolved

Comment: In your case fetch request will resolve in a string containing the whole html page. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I try to render de received html page. It doesn't happen

Comment: I have edited the answer. May be this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, himank. Maybe I have not been able to explain the problem clearly.
1.- I use fetch () from the browser to be able to enter in the header of the request the token jwt that I have stored in localstorage.
2.- The controller responds with a render ("myPage.html")
3.- The clause .then of the fetch catchs the response and I render it with the document.write (response) instruction.
4.- This works but it is a fudge because the browser's address window and navigation history are not modified

Comment: 5.- Maybe the solution is to use another method to make the request from the browser, taking into account that I have to modify the header of the request to introduce the token jwt
6.- Thanks for your answers

Comment: This is the response the client receive after the server send de response with res.render("brands/brands, <locals vars>)
- response: Response
- body:ReadableStream  
- bodyUsed:false  
- headers:Headers {}  
- ok:true  
- redirected:false  
- status:200  
- statusText:"OK"  
- type:"basic"  
- url:"http://localhost:3000/api/brands"  
All is ok, but How can I render in the front-end the url :"http://localhost:3000/api/brands"?
Until now, I have transformed the response in a text (res.text()) and then I render with document.write(). But that's not a good solution

Comment: But then, how can I insert headers in the request? I need to insert the Authorization token

Comment: You can set cookie with your token  and will get it in each request to server. Then you can check the authentication of the user.